# Installation to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I tried installation using Vbox/Ubuntu 20.04. Screen is too small, but using Tab-Tab-Enter I reached partitioning screen, which ended with failure.

What is procedure to instal Odin to VBox?

Comment: this worked for me !! all i had to do was enable efi and it fixed the issue i was having. the issue was i couldnt see the full screen resolution to download elementary os

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for the VM, open the System section and go to the Motherboard tab. Under Extended Features, check the **Enable EFI (special OSes only)** box. This *should* enable it to boot. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could first enter the Live "Testing" mode (by "Tab-Tab-Enter"), then change to a higher screen resolution in the Live-Session, and then start the OS-Installer from within the Live-Session.

This worked for me. *cheers#