# Running latest version of VMware Workstation Pro 16.x but cannot install Elementary OS 6 due to UI dialog being too big

Tags: install, virtualization

Running VMware Workstation Pro 16.1.x on Windows. Cannot install Elementary OS 6 from VM because display area is too small.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: I am also testing elementary for the 1st time. I am experiencing the same challenge. I did manage to install it by using the tab and guessing which button is next. Ie, after choosing language, I used TAB twice and then Space. Then I played with TAB sequence and space until it elementary started installing. I also tried all the Vmware fusion display settings, non worked

Comment: I have the same problem, and tab or space guessing doesn't work.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0MhG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0MhG.png) Please any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with VMWare Workstation 16.1.x till I reach this post and took the advice posted previously of Colin Dean regarding EFI Mode
The issue that I wasn't able to reach this option through the VMWare GUI, so after a quick google search, all the needed to solve the issue is the below :

- Create your Elementary OS
- No need to start it yet
- Go to the machine .VMX file
- add the below in the second line of the VMX file

> firmware="efi"

- Save the .VMX file
- Boot your machine

This solved the issue for me, please try it and let me know :)

[image: VMXFileFirmwareEFI]

Answer (score 0):

On *VirtualBox*, you have to [enable EFI mode](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/28403/26625). Perhaps there is a similar setting for VMWare.