# Elementary OS 6 ISO unable to install in VMWare and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Installing in VMWare Workstation Player, the display is so small that it makes it impossible to reply to the multiple installation screens.  There should the option to start as a live session, then enlarge the display resolution and then start the installation.

In VirtualBox, when poiting to the ISO (checksum verified), and trying to start this ISO file, I got the error:
"FATAL: No bootable media found! System halted".
It is the same media that started installation in VMWare, without errors, just the small screen.

I have many linux distros installed in both VMWare and VirtualBox all running without problems.

Comment: Got the same issue - i tried the suggestion above tab-tab-enter until you reach to CLI installation window and you'll see extracting...

Answer (score 1):

I am newbie with elementary. Want to try it out on VMWare and stuck with the small screen. Looking at the "Select a Language" page helplessly...

It seems slow too...

[image]

EDIT: Found a solution on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/p2zsss/cannot_install_odin_on_virtualbox_because_of/h8nrthu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

//
added a line to the VM file (.vmx), so the first three lines look like this:

.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
firmware="efi"

Answer (score 0):

In VMWare using "Tab-tab-enter" I could manage to install Elementary OS without having all the installation screens fully displayed.  This should not happen.

It remains the error reported in Virtualbox to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it should be fixed by developers, but in the meantime, also [see this tread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/installation-to-virtualbox). It works.

Answer (score 0):

Enter a key while boot countdown is still running and add vga=ask to the list of kernel parameters and then get the list of possible resolutions displayed and choose one. Did work for me without hassle.

By the way: since this is a kernel parameter it works for all distros.